# how is work with str_replace to array?

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace, json

why not worked str_replace? what do i do?

```
$date = $this->convert_date->JalaliToGregorian('1390','04','20'); ->> this output with json_encode -> [2011,7,11]
$da =  str_replace(",","/",$date);
echo json_encode ($da) ->> output  Array ["2011","7","11"]
```

Comment: Is variable `$date` a JSON string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commas are not in the array.  That's being added by json_encode. Try `implode("/", $date);`  That will combine the three array elements using  `/` as glue.

[Implode Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 1):

json_encode returns a string which represents the JSON representation of an object. In the case of Arrays, that is a comma delineated list surrounded by commas. If you want to have the array be delineated by something else, then you should use [`implode($glue,$pieces)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
implode("/", $date);
```

As a bit of a gotcha -- implode will work based on key insertion order so you may want to use ksort first:

```
$a = array(1=>1, 0=>0); 
echo implode(",", $a); // outputs 1,0
ksort( $a );
echo implode(",", $a); // outputs 0,1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'am not entirely sure what do you expect as a result. 
If you want your script to output '2011/7/11', then you shoul use implode() instead of str_replace (since $date is not a string, but an array).
So

$da = implode('/', $date);

would give you that result

Comment: if use of implode output is: "2011\/7\/11"

Comment: yes, that is perfectly correct, the slashes '/' are escaped in JSON format, so they are written as \/. The application which processes this JSON string will read this correctly as '2011/7/11'

Comment: how converted of "2011\/7\/11 to  '2011/7/11'?

Comment: If you want '2011/7/11' as a result, then remove the json_encode() function call. If you want JSON string as a result, the '2011\/7\/11' is correct display of '2011/7/11' string - so you don't convert it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, whether I understand you correctly, but this may be a solution:

```
echo implode('/', $date);
```

This will glue the elements of `$date` array with `/` into this string:

> 2011/7/11

Please see [CodePad.org snippet](http://codepad.org/7J16VuL9) for a proof.

Comment: if use of implode output is: "2011\/7\/11"

Comment: @Mehd S: the output is exactly what I have written and yours looks different because of mechanism that escapes slashes (`/` characters). This can happen in many situations, one of which is when you json_encode it (like [in this example](http://codepad.org/KptDclUg)). This is completely natural and correct and this is a way of representing `2011/7/11` string in JSON. You can read more about JSON [here](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: how converted of "2011\/7\/11 to  '2011/7/11'?

Comment: @Mehd S: `"2011\/7\/11"` is only a *representation* of `2011/7/11` string within JSON format. To get this value from JSON object, you can just (assuming `$date` is JSON string containing this string) `json_decode()` it.